# How to show autofill suggestion for email field as it is showing in password field in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I want that once user logging in Chrome saving login details but like the way password field is showing suggestion for autofill , email field will also
show autofill suggestion for email. Even though autocomplete is off for password but it is showing for it but even after making autocomplete ON for email , it is not showing
It is React js and these are my fields

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Autofill behavior in browsers is ultimately controlled by the browser itself, and each browser may handle it slightly differently. However, there are some general practices you can follow to enhance the autofill experience for email fields in React.

1-Ensure Proper HTML Attributes:
Make sure your email input field has the appropriate HTML attributes:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" />
```

Setting type="email" and autoComplete="email" helps the browser recognize the field as an email input and encourages it to suggest email addresses for autofill.

2-Form Tag:
Make sure your email input is inside a  tag. Browsers often associate autofill data with specific forms.

```
<form>
  <input type="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" />
  {/* other form fields and submit button */}
</form>
```

3-Unique Form Identifiers:
Ensure that your form has a unique identifier. Browsers use the combination of form fields and the form's identifier to associate autofill data.

4-Check Browser Settings:
Make sure the user has autofill and password saving enabled in their browser settings. In Chrome, for example, users can check these settings in "Settings" > "Autofill" > "Passwords" and make sure the feature is enabled.

5-JavaScript and React Handling:
Ensure that your JavaScript or React code is not interfering with the default browser behavior. If you have any event handlers, form submissions, or custom code related to the form, make sure it doesn't prevent the browser from handling autofill.

```
    // Example of preventing form submission in a React component
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your form submission logic
};

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {/* form fields */}
</form>
```

Remember that while you can encourage browsers to suggest autofill data, the final decision is up to the browser and the user's settings. If a user has explicitly disabled autofill for email addresses or if the browser doesn't recognize the field as an email input, it may not suggest autofill data.